# Display only groups in Highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, data-visualization, r-highcharter

I'm using something similar to the following code to display bar chart groupwise:

```
library(purrr) # map function to make grouped categories argument
library(dplyr) # for select function 

data(mpg, package = "ggplot2")

mpgg <- mpg %>% 
  filter(class %in% c("suv", "compact", "midsize")) %>% 
  group_by(class, manufacturer) %>% 
  summarize(count = n())

categories_grouped <- mpgg %>% 
  group_by(name = class) %>% 
  do(categories = .$manufacturer) %>% 
  list_parse()

highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = categories_grouped) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = mpgg, type = "bar", hcaes(y = count, color = manufacturer),
                showInLegend = FALSE)
```

I'm getting the following chart:

[Highchart Group Categories Wise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4g96.png)

Because of the misalignment, I just want to display groups without categories. I have tried several solutions but there is always some alignment issue.

Any solutions?

Comment: Hi. What do you mean saying "misalignment" and "I just want to display groups without categories"?

Comment: @raf18seb For example, in Compact Class, Manufacturer Name - "Volkswagen" is spilling out of the cell. I just want to display - Class Name (Compact, Midsize, and SUV. Not the manufacturer names.)

Comment: It is a known grouped categories module issue. You can move your labels a little bit using labels.x property: "  hc_xAxis(categories = categories_grouped, labels = list(x = -6)) %>% 
"
Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @raf18seb Thanks. But my category names are quite large. Any other way to display just group names.

Comment: You can find a similar issue explained here: https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/issues/62#issuecomment-113094625
I will think about displaying only group names now.

Comment: What about not using grouped categories but standard categories? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/29kgtp3u

Comment: Ok, I will write the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need two groups of categories, you can just define standard categories without grouped-categories.js module like in this JS example: jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/29kgtp3u